# Laravel x7 base de datos no encontrada en 'laravel'

Tags: mysql, xampp, laravel-7

Estoy tratando de hacer un insert:

```
$datosEmpleado=request()->except('_token');
Empleados::insert($datosEmpleado);
```

Pero me indica:

- Unknown database 'laravel'

archivo .env tiene el nombre de la BD _sistema

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=_sistema
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Para las migraciones no tuve problemas
[image: BD en phpmyadmin]

Comment: muestra tu config/database.php

Comment: Solo borra tu cache, `config:cache`

Comment: @sgClaudia98 encontre el problema, al instalar laravel la primera ves lo hice en /lampp/laravel, este proyecto que intente correr esta en /lampp/htdocs, entonces cuando hice el insert, este se intento hacer sobre el proyecto en la carpeta laravel. Ahorita borre ese proyecto y pude hacer el insert, pero sigo sin poder visualizar mi proyecto con la url localhost/sistema/public, aparece denegado: `The stream or file "/opt/lampp/htdocs/sistema/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permiso denegado` @Shassain ya habia intentado borrar la bd y limpiar cache gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenia dos proyectos uno en:

- /lampp/htdocs/sistema
- /lampp/laravel/primero

al momento de hacer el insert este buscaba hacerlo sobre el proyecto llamado primero.

Al eliminarlo pude hacer el insert
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]